# How to paste a string into EditText without being restricted by the InputType?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText`field, where the user can switch between two kind of keyboards (alphabetic and numeric only). This works great, but when the user wants to paste a specific string, e.g. `AB12AB` and the numeric keyboard is currently opened, it will just paste `12` (cut all non-digits out) into the field.

For switching keybords, I currently use the method `.setInputType(...)`, but the problem is, that every string which is pasted into the textfield will be filtered by the currently set InputType.

How can I paste any kind of strings into the textfield without being restricted by the currently set InputType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statically this problem can be solved by adding:
`android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` to the .xml file of the EditText object. It is important, that `android:inputType="number"` is also set, otherwise it won't work.

Every time the InputMethod of the EditText object is changed dynamically, the current attribute is overriden, so if you want to add the `android:digits="..."` attribute back, you can achieve that by adding a [KeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.html):

`.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));`

Note that setting the DigitsKeyListener will also set an InputType (see in reference), so you don't have to call `.setInputType(...)` again.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```